# Wrong snapshot on firebase queryOrdered byChild

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the media that have been saved only by `adminUserUID`.
The problem is that the data returned is not what has been posted by `adminUserUID`.
I see no mistake in my code and I don't understand why I get the wrong data.

My data structure looks like this

```
media
 -L_2xS9LlY5hfXDErbde  //<- childByAutoID
     mediaUID: "-L_2xS9LlY5hfXDErbde"
     type: "video"
     userUID:  "Y9tm718aXrWK78i7mkOLNF57X2j1"
```

Code:

```
 var adminUserUID = "uek3xKdQdogHAYxJhDrMMoSj82x1"


 let ref = Database.database().reference()

     ref.child("media").queryOrdered(byChild: adminUserUID).queryLimited(toLast: 4)     

  class func observeChildAddedPostsOf(query: DatabaseQuery, _ completion: @escaping (Media) -> Void) {
    query.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        guard snapshot.exists() else {print("snapshot on line \(#line) is nil")
            return
        }
        let media = Media(dictionary: snapshot.value as! [String : Any])
        completion(media)
    })
}
```

Pods

```
 - Firebase (5.20.2):
    - Firebase/Core (= 5.20.2)
  - Firebase/Auth (5.20.2):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAuth (= 5.4.2)
  - Firebase/Core (5.20.2):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 5.8.1)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (5.20.2):
    - FirebaseCore (= 5.4.1)
  - Firebase/Database (5.20.2):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseDatabase (= 5.1.1)
  - Firebase/DynamicLinks (5.20.2):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseDynamicLinks (= 3.4.3)
  - Firebase/Messaging (5.20.2):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseMessaging (= 3.5.0)
  - Firebase/Storage (5.20.2):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseStorage (= 3.1.1)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (5.8.1):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 5.4)
```

Comment: you dont have `uek3xKdQdogHAYxJhDrMMoSj82x1` in the database

Comment: @PeterHaddad I will check in a moment. However, if that value is not in the database, why does it return the node containing `Y9tm718aXrWK78i7mkOLNF57X2j1 ` ? It should return an empty snapshot..

Comment: @PeterHaddad I have double checked manually in the database and it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does not do what you think it does:

```
ref.child("media").queryOrdered(byChild: adminUserUID)
```

This code takes all children of the `media` node, and orders them by the value of their `adminUserUID` property. In the JSON you show, no child node has a property named `"uek3xKdQdogHAYxJhDrMMoSj82x1"`.

If your goal is to get all child nodes order by the value of their `userUID` property:

```
ref.child("media").queryOrdered(byChild: "userUID")
```

If your goal is to get all child nodes whose `userUID` property has a value `"uek3xKdQdogHAYxJhDrMMoSj82x1"`:

```
ref.child("media").queryOrdered(byChild: "userUID").queryValue(equalTo: "uek3xKdQdogHAYxJhDrMMoSj82x1")
```

Comment: I understand your examples and my approach is clearly wrong. I am wondering, is there any way I can achieve the desired result in only one query for this question? I know that chaining multiple queries is not possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430882