# How to query firebase data childByAutoID?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is is possible to query this path in **only one go** and order the items by `locality` value (e.g London), but get only the items which are starting/ending at a certain `childByAutoID`?

**Reason -** when I scroll down in a tableView, I want to get from database more older items ordered by a certain area, e.g London and older than `oldestKey` which is the key of the media item.

The first batch of items is downloaded initially using `.childAdded` method.

Data:

```
 media
   -LgSsaqYzevONPTk2447 // <- childByAutoID
       caption: "12"
       locality: "City of London"
       mediaUID: "-LgSsaqYzevONPTk2447"

  -LgSsZnpSNLJwZBNgXGJ
       caption: "15"
       locality: "New York"
       mediaUID: "-LgSsZnpSNLJwZBNgXGJ"
```

Code

```
   class func observeNewMediaSingleTime(_ oldestKey: String,_ 
  userLocality: String, _ completion: @escaping ([Media], String?) -> Void) {


   let ref = Database.database().reference()
     let query = ref.child("media").queryOrdered(byChild: userLocality).queryStarting(atValue: oldestKey).queryLimited(toLast: 50)


 ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

    guard snapshot.exists() else {
        completion([],nil)
        return}

     let firstItem = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as! DataSnapshot

      var arrayOfMedia = [Media]()

     var count = 0
     let enumerator = snapshot.children
     while let mediaItem = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
        let media = Media(dictionary: mediaItem.value as! [String:Any])

        print("media.locality is \(media.locality)")
        //check if new media has same key as oldest post downloaded in previously
        if media.mediaUID != oldestKey{
            count += 1
            arrayOfMedia.append(media)
        }
    }//end of while
    arrayOfMedia.reverse()

    if count == arrayOfMedia.count {
        let updatedOldestKey = firstItem.key
        completion(arrayOfMedia, updatedOldestKey)
    }

})
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the `locality` value of the first item, this is possible with [`queryStarting(atValue:childKey:)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseQuery#querystartingatvalue:childkey:):

```
let query = ref.child("media")
  .queryOrdered(byChild: "locality")
  .queryStarting(atValue: "City of London", childKey: "-LgSsaqYzevONPTk2447")
  .queryLimited(toLast: 50)
```

So the above orders all child nodes by their locality, and then starts returning results at the with with `locality`=`"City of London"` and key `-LgSsaqYzevONPTk2447`.

Comment: This is clearly not doing what it is supposed to do. Even though there are 20 items saved in the database where `locality` == `"City of London"`, it downloads items with other areas. Just for the sake of this example, I saved 20 items one after another with same locality value and it pulls data from other towns.... I don't know what to do. https://imgur.com/LEXwg8l

Comment: `.queryStarting(atValue: "City of London"` **starts** at the ones with `"City of London"`, but continues to return childs with other `locality` values. If you don't want that, you need to `queryEnding(atValue: ...` too.

Comment: I have just found out that while I've been testing. Patience is a virtue only few can master and I have run out of it today; my bad. Many thanks. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: One problem. It has pulled about 30 items from the database, but now it is not pulling any more data even though there is plenty of it. I used `...queryOrdered(byChild: "locality").queryEnding(atValue: userLocality, childKey: oldestKey)` where `locality` == "City of London" and `childKey` is always the key of the first  item that was previously downloaded. I have noticed it downloaded some items with `locality` == `Buckinghamshire`, but now it is not pulling more, even though they have same locality name. It pulls 1, but not 2. https://imgur.com/a/1rx7pkG . These last items are 6months old.

Comment: If you order the child nodes on `locality`, then `"Buckinghamshire"` is *before* `"City of London"`. So if you start at "City of London", you won't get child nodes with Buckinghamshire.

Comment: It really sounds like you want to order by key, then start at a specific key, and then return results from there. If that's what you want, you'll have to sort them on `locality` client-side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194398/discussion-between-bibscy-and-frank-van-puffelen).